# Error con filtro de fecha en ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Saludos tengo una vista con un CRUD en asp mvc y estoy intentando hacer un filtrado de fecha, mediante un procedure pero al momento de precionar el boton de filtrado me da el siguiente error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[Pharmcom.Models.fechaUnion_Result]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Pharmcom.Models.Union]'.

En la vista tengo: `@model IEnumerable<Pharmcom.Models.Union>`

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PharmcomEntities DB = new PharmcomEntities();
        return View(DB.Union.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        //fechaUnion = procedure
        PharmcomEntities DB = new PharmcomEntities();
        return View(db.fechaUnion(start, end));
    }
```

El modelo del procedure:

```
 public partial class fechaUnion_Result
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FECHA { get; set; }
    public string NO_DOCUMENTO { get; set; }
    public string ID_CLIENTE { get; set; }
    public string NOMBRE_CLIENTE { get; set; }
    public string ID_ARTICULO { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPCION { get; set; }
    public decimal CANT { get; set; }
    public string UND { get; set; }
    public decimal PRECIO_VENTA { get; set; }
    public decimal DESCUENTO { get; set; }
    public decimal IMPUESTO { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int PROVINCIA { get; set; }
    public string Expr1 { get; set; }
    public decimal VENTA { get; set; }
    public int Region { get; set; }
}
```

modelo de la tabla:

```
 public partial class Union
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FECHA { get; set; }
    public string NO_DOCUMENTO { get; set; }
    public string ID_CLIENTE { get; set; }
    public string NOMBRE_CLIENTE { get; set; }
    public string ID_ARTICULO { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPCION { get; set; }
    public decimal CANT { get; set; }
    public string UND { get; set; }
    public decimal PRECIO_VENTA { get; set; }
    public decimal DESCUENTO { get; set; }
    public decimal IMPUESTO { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int PROVINCIA { get; set; }
    public string Expr1 { get; set; }
    public decimal VENTA { get; set; }
    public int Region { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Puedes indicar en la pregunta que tienes en la directiva `@model` de la Vista?. Indica también el Modelo `Union`.

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica en que tu Vista `Index.cshtml` requiere un Modelo del tipo `IEnumerable<Pharmcom.Models.Union>` en la Acción **GET**, y tu le estás pasando un objeto del tipo `Pharmcom.Models.fechaUnion_Result`cuando haces el **POST** y devuelves el Modelo a la Vista.

Para solucionar esta eventualidad, lo que se suele hacer es utilizar un **ViewModel** para la Vista, que **incluya ambos Modelos**.

Para ello crea el ViewModel **`IndexViewModel`** de esta manera (*en la carpeta Pharmcom/Models*):

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<Union> Union { get; set; }
    public List<fechaUnion_Result> FechaUnionResult { get; set; }
}
```

Luego modifica la directiva @model de la vista para que acepte un objeto del tipo `IndexViewModel`:

```
@model Pharmcom.Models.IndexViewModel
```

Y en el Controlador, devuelve siempre un objeto del tipo **`IndexViewModel`** con las propiedades cargadas en función de lo que necesites:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PharmcomEntities DB = new PharmcomEntities();

        IndexViewModel indexViewModel = new IndexViewModel()
        {
            Union = DB.Union.ToList()
        };
        return View(indexViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        //fechaUnion = procedure
        PharmcomEntities DB = new PharmcomEntities();

        IndexViewModel indexViewModel = new IndexViewModel()
        {
            FechaUnionResult = db.fechaUnion(start, end).ToList()
        };
        return View(indexViewModel);
    }
```

Luego en la Vista accede a cada propiedad del Modelo **`IndexViewModel`**, en función de lo que quieras hacer:

**`@Model.Union`** o **`@Model.FechaUnionResult`**

Comment: Saludos @Rafael, gracias por tu excelente respuesta pero tengo un problema en el codigo `FechaUnionResult = db.fechaUnion(start, end)`                       dice: **no puede escribir implícitamente 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult <Pharmcom.Models.fechaUnion_Result>' a 'Pharmcom.Models.fechaUnion_Result'**

Comment: Disculpa la molestia soy un poco novato en esto, como podria hacer el Cast?

Comment: Perdona, hazle un `TolList()`. He modificado la respuesta, revísala.

Comment: Error CS0029 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List <Pharmcom.Models.fechaUnion_Result>' a

Comment: Has modificado el Modelo `IndexViewModel` y el Controlador ?. Vuelve a leer la respuesta, está modificada.

Comment: Cierto disculpa en no fijarme, lo que no entendí del todo es la ultima parte de en la Vista accede a cada propiedad del Modelo IndexViewModel, en función de lo que quieras hacer.